# check for content change of a web site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a **Google chrome extension** which can check for the any new article (content update) of a web site. As this have to be done using **javascript code** so how can i monitor any given web site whose web url is known using javascript code.

Any tutorial or article related to this will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you want this to actually find the differences, or just tell you when the site has changed so that you can go look at it?

Comment: Only it should tell when site has changed.

Comment: That isn't too difficult, I was going to suggest what Joe has recommended below. Read the relevant section of the website, hash it and compare it to the hash that you computed last time the program ran. If the hash is different, something has changed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what you need to do with said information, but a very simple method would be to crawl the website and create a md5 hash (or any hash really) of each page, and compare that to a stored hash value.  If it's not the same value, then some change has occurred (perhaps a very minor change, but you don't specify how large of a change is needed).

Example JavaScript hash code can be found on http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ .

Comment: I want to check for useful changes in main content of website.I think what you have suggested will show update even if an advertisement is added or updated in a website (which is not the main content of web site).

Comment: Defining 'useful' is, unfortunately, well beyond the scope of anything here.  You can try to limit what you read/hash to a certain div/etc., but it's generally going to require a fairly specific set of code for the website (probably not very generalizable).

Comment: Isn't it possible to detect changes by [retrieving the page's ETag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203322/975097) without downloading or hashing the page's content?

Comment: This question is over ten years old, but you can suggest a close-as-duplicate if you want as it does look like that question has better answers (though I don't know anything about entity tags, so don't know if it's actually a workable solution nowadays).