# How to detect change on webpage without reload

Tags: python

I found ho to detect by using perl. 
[How to detect a changed webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201009/how-to-detect-a-changed-webpage])
But unfortunatelly I don't know perl.
Is there a way in python? 
Can you give a detailed example if you do not complicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean an python script, which reads a webpage and shows you if it is different from the last visit? A very simple version would be this (works for python2 and python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import requests
from hashlib import sha1

recent_hash_filename = ".recent_hash"


def test(url):
    print("looking up %s" % url)
    if not os.path.exists(recent_hash_filename):
        open(recent_hash_filename, 'a').close()

    hash_fetched = sha1()
    hash_read    = ""
    r = requests.get(url)
    hash_fetched.update(r.text.encode("utf8"))

    with open(recent_hash_filename) as f:
        hash_read = f.read()

    print(hash_fetched.hexdigest())
    print(hash_read)

    if hash_fetched.hexdigest() == hash_read:
        print("same")
    else:
        print("different")

    with open(recent_hash_filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(hash_fetched.hexdigest())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        url = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        url = "https://www.heise.de"

    test(url)

    print("done")
```

If you have any questions just let me know